# How to integrate auth0 in vue using typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, authentication, auth0

I am new to typescript. I am able to integrate auth0 using javascript because auth0 providing a sample for that but there is no sample app available for vue with typescript. please let me know any links or samples.

Comment: Auth0 does not currently have a typescript implementation, but there is one in progress, but I have no ETA as of today. Your best bet right now is to give it a shot and post the issues you run into along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample app provided from the official `vue js` docs, just choose your preferred backend tool for those listed in the link:
https://auth0.com/developers/hub/code-samples/full-stack/hello-world/basic-role-based-access-control/spa/vue-3-typescript